# How to test the existence of a file in a case-sensitive manner?

Tags: files-and-directories

I noticed (using Mathematica 11.2 on Windows) that `FileExistsQ["test.txt"]` returns `True`even if there only exists a file `"TEST.txt"` in the current directory.
How can one test the existence of a file in a case-sensitive manner?

Comment: `FileExistsQ` must use the Windows API to check and it's not case-sensitive _(note the filesystem NTFS itself **is** in fact case-sensitive)_ . Use `MemberQ[FileNames[], "test.txt"]` instead.

Comment: Thank you Flinty. This is what I was looking for. Couls you please put your comment into an answer?